# Make a javascript function be called when the value after hash changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I call a javascript function every time the URL has a change with the string after the hash?

for example
.com/onepage/

(onwindowload called)

.com/#1000

(need a function to be called)

.com/#500

(need a function to be called)

Comment: `window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);`  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange).

Comment: https://github.com/millermedeiros/hasher/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way......

```
window.location.watch(
    'hash',
    function(id,oldVal,newVal){
        console.log(oldval+" to "+newVal);
        //Do something.........
    }
);
```

Comment: This only works in firefox